# Mongo will not load in phpinfo with error_reporting enabled

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, ubuntu, error-reporting

I have been trying to get Mongo to work on PHP 5.3 with Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 for several hours now.

It was giving the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/projects/learn/create.php on line 7
```

Mongo was showing up in `php -m` but not in `phpinfo()`. After a very long search I tried commenting the following in my `php.ini`:

```
Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

This causes Mongo to appear in my `phpinfo()` statement, and `$m = new MongoClient()` doesn't throw any errors. The only problem is that I need error reporting turned on (as I am a new developer).

What could possibly be causing Mongo to fail to load only when verbose error reporting is enabled?

edit: Also of possible note is I turned on error reporting in the individual PHP file and that shows any errors properly, while still letting Mongo load

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean by commenting `Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` in your php.ini. This line should always be commented out because it is a comment. It also has nothing to do with whether Mongo will load or not.

Comment: `php -m` is command line, so you probably ran phpinfo() under a webserver. different .ini files, so probably the mongo stuff is not being loaded in whatever .ini(s) the webserver's copy of php is looking at. phpinfo() will tell you exactly which files ARE being loaded.

Comment: For some reason this value was uncommented on my installation by default - I am guessing this halted the load of php.ini before it got to the extension line. Perhaps I need to take a look at my php.ini syntax - thanks!

Comment: @wcpyro sounds like a good idea. You may also want to just revert it to the default. You can do this either by purging the `php5` package and reinstalling it (or trying to find a default php.ini file somewhere on the internet that matches your OS and hope for the best).

Answer (score 2):

In all probability the mongo extension is not installed on your dev/server setup. first check whether it is installed. create a file called phpinfo.php with the contents:

run it from the browser. search for mongo. see what the version is. if it is not present do the following from the command line:

sudo pecl install mongo

if you have ubuntu desktop
sudo gedit /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini

if you have ubuntu server
sudo vi /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini

insert the following line in the file:
extension=mongo.so

save the file. exit. restart apache with sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

never directly edit the php.ini file for loading/unloading extensions in ubuntu. do the changes in the files at /etc/php5/conf.d/